# Rescaling border failure

Tags: javascript, resize

After many trials we managed to fix our wallpaper to full width and add black bars above and below - now our problem is the resizing. We tried our best but it just doesn't work.

Here is our JS code:

```
var balken = document.getElementById("source-img").height / 2;
    balkencount = balken * 0.97;
    balken = balken * 0.8;

    document.getElementById("mailtable").style.marginTop = balken + "px";
    document.getElementById("countdowntable").style.marginTop = -balkencount + "px";
```

Comment: Is Javascript really needed here? Can you post your HTML markup or better yet a fiddle? There may be a way to accomplish what you need using a fluid CSS layout

Comment: Yes, I think so at least .. it's a cut from a full sized video to the wallpaper :)